# Is the start relay for my Whirlpool broken? It rattles

Tags: refrigerator, relay

My fridge has stopped cooling and with some cursory research I've determined that the problem may be the start relay. I've seen this diagnosed by shaking it to listen to any rattling sound. Does this sound broken or is this sound normal?
https://youtu.be/_foQSKoBFSs

Thank you in advance

Comment: your video is not working

Comment: A working relay may "rattle" when shaken, if you shake it in the direction it normally moves in...

Comment: @Ruskes sorry can you check now?

Comment: @keshlam I see, can you give me video a look?

Comment: @Ruskes Thank you, if you want to post an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Go ahed you answer it

Comment: Duplicate of https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/149063/is-a-refrigerator-start-relay-supposed-rattle-not-cooling?